# How to set Active Choice Parameter's script sandbox via Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a JobDSL script that creates a Jenkins pipeline job with Active Choice parameters provided by Active Choice Parameters plugin. Unfortunately, JobDSL doesn't support parameter that enables running Active Choice Groovy scripts in sandbox (in UI it's available), so I'm trying to enable it via configure block.

Here's my JobDSL script:

```
pipelineJob("my-pipeline") {
  logRotator(-1, 10)
  parameters {
    activeChoiceParam('Branch') {
      description('Lists branches for integration job')
      filterable()
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      groovyScript {
          script("return ['The list of branches']")
          fallbackScript("return ['Unable to list branches']")
      }
    }
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('Build') {
      description('Specifies which build from selected branch will be used for deployment. Only builds that contain Terraform plan are listed.')
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      groovyScript {
          script("return ['Selected build']")
          fallbackScript("return ['Unable to list builds']")
      }
      referencedParameter('Branch')
    }
    activeChoiceReactiveReferenceParam('Artifacts') {
      description('Lists artifacts from build specified')
      choiceType('FORMATTED_HTML')
      groovyScript {
          script(scriptGen("return ['Job artifacts']")
          fallbackScript("return ['Unable to list artifacts']")
      }
      referencedParameter('Branch')
      referencedParameter('Build')
    }
  }
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            github('mainorg/my-repo', 'https', 'github.com')
            credentials('my-creds')
          }
          branch('*/master')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("ci/Jenkinsfile")
      lightweight(true)
    }
  }
  configure { 
      it / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionPropert' / 'parameterDefinitions' / 'org.biouno.unochoice.ChoiceParameter' / 'script' / 'secureScript' {
        'sandbox'('true')
    }
  }
}
```

With `configure` block, I'm trying to override values for `<secureFallbackScript>` and `<secureScript>` under`<sandbox>` node, but it doesn't work. It erases all other nodes. I'm not that good at Groovy, so I would really appreciate any help.
What is the correct way to override all `<sandbox>` nodes values to `true`? Thanks in advance.

Here's a link to job XML for reference: https://gist.github.com/vzabawski/aae51eddd45a51978224e403cc505b5b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `activeChoiceParam`, `activeChoiceReactiveParam` and `activeChoiceReactiveReferenceParam` functions are parts of the static API. The Job DSL authors introduced the [dynamic API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL). Whenever the dynamic API could be used to do something, the static API responsible for the same logic is no longer supported.

You should read those pages:

- [Job DSL Dynamic API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL)
- [JENKINS-41308 support Use Groovy Sandbox scripts in activeChoiceParams](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41308)

An example how to switch from the static API to the dynamic API:

```
activeChoiceParam('Branch') {
  description('Lists branches for integration job')
  filterable()
  choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
  groovyScript {
    script("return ['The list of branches']")
    fallbackScript("return ['Unable to list branches']")
  }
}
```

↓

```
choiceParameter {
  name('Branch')
  description('Lists branches for integration job')
  filterable(true)
  choiceType('PT_SINGLE_SELECT')
  script {
    groovyScript {
      script {
        script("return ['The list of branches']")
        sandbox(true)
      }
      fallbackScript {
        script("return ['Unable to list branches']")
        sandbox(true)
      }
    }
  }
  randomName('')
  filterLength(0)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR: (infrastructure_jobs_ccloud.groovy, line 100) No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Branch]
Possible solutions: wait(), chars(), any(), wait(long), split(java.lang.String), any(groovy.lang.Closure)`, which is weird. Trying to find the reason.

Comment: I'm quite sure you did something like: `def name = 'Job Name'; choiceParameter { name(name)`. In such case the script cannot resolve the `name` method (it is hidden by the `name` variable). You have to use the `delegate` object to point to the method: `def name = 'Job Name'; choiceParameter { delegate.name(name) `.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had a variable at the beginning of the code and I forgot about its existence. Thank you very much.

Comment: Worth mentioning: `SINGLE_SELECT` should be replaced with `PT_SINGLE_SELECT`.

Comment: OMG I spent days trying to get the sandbox checkmark propagated to the UI from pipelineJob DSL. I pasted yours in and migrated my old code. I ran into problems because I missed the subtle difference in dynamic api where the "groovyScript" block ins encapsulated by a "script" block and the inner "script" block contains a "script()" method call... something to pay attention to when converting from old style to new.